# How to change parent after opacity of the selected child?

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm looking a way using css to change the parent opacity value, on after, if it's contains a selected child class. 
What I have accomplished so far is only the hover state. On hover I'm adding a background color to the parent on ::after. Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<ul class="slider-thumbs">
  <li class="reason-item"><a>Item 1</a></li>
  <li class="reason-item"><a class="selected">Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="reason-item"><a>Item 3</a></li>
  <li class="reason-item"><a>Item 4</a></li>
  <li class="reason-item"><a>Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider-thumbs .reason-item{position: relative;vertical-align: top;}
.slider-thumbs .reason-item::after {content: '\A';position: absolute;width: 100%; height:100%;top:0; left:0;background:rgba(252,194,38,0.9);opacity: 0;transition: all 1s;-webkit-transition: all 1s;}
.slider-thumbs .reason-item:hover::after, .slider-thumbs .reason-item:after + a.selected{opacity: 1;}
```

So when the user selected one of the available items I want to change the opacity value of the parent (`::after`) which contains a class selected, in order for the end user to see what he/she selected when the page loads.

Here is my code working with the hover state.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/giwrgos/0vLmkhr2/1/**

Comment: I just updated my answer and I think that will be a good start for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `:after` from the last rule, because after the `::after` pseudo element doesn't exist `a.selected`.

So your final code will be:

```css
.slider-thumbs .reason-item{
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.slider-thumbs .reason-item::after {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height:100%;
  top:0; 
  left:0;
  background:rgba(252,194,38,0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
.slider-thumbs .reason-item:hover::after, 
.slider-thumbs .reason-item + a.selected{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slider-thumbs">
<li class="reason-item"><a>Item 1</a></li>
<li class="reason-item"><a class="selected">Item 2</a></li>
<li class="reason-item"><a>Item 3</a></li>
<li class="reason-item"><a>Item 4</a></li>
<li class="reason-item"><a>Item 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

See your edited fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0vLmkhr2/3/

Comment: When you hover in some element its background changes to yellow with a smooth transition

Comment: What browser are you using or what is the expected behaviour? I test this in firefox and chrome (lastest versions) and it works perfectly

Comment: The hover state it was working also on my example. The thing that it didn;t work and I'm looking is to have yellow background to the li which has child selected

Comment: First of all your example doesn't works for me, **at least in firefox**, so use the code in my answer to make it bulletproof. In second case, you can't target a parent element with CSS, you will need javascript/jquery to make it

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to only use css by traversing back up the DOM as its not built that way. 
If you have the class `selected` you could use jQuery to :-

```
$(".selected").find().parent("li").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the style to apply on the a instead of the li so now it's working. here is the code

```
.slider-thumbs li{position: relative; }
.slider-thumbs a {vertical-align: top; display:block; word-break: break-word;}
.slider-thumbs a::after {
  content: '\A';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; 
  height:100%;
  top:0; 
  left:0;
  background:rgba(252,194,38,0.9);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
}
.slider-thumbs a:hover::after, 
.slider-thumbs a.selected{
  opacity: 1;
}
```